# React-native on Android Network Resource Image Fails to Load

Tags: android, react-native

My Android operating system is 5.1 , React-natvie is 0.50.1 ,I set it according to the official website tutorial, but it's useless

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Image style={{width:300, height:300}} 
    source={{url: 'https://example.com/image.jpg'}} />
    <Text>hello world</Text>
  </View>
```

it just shows hello world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to `uri`, you have used `url`

```
<Image style={{width:300, height:300}} 
source={{uri: 'https://example.com/image.jpg'}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check Android Manifest to see whether you add this permission:

   android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
2. Update your code:

```html
<View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={{width:300, height:300}} 
        source={{uri: 'https://example.com/image.jpg'}} />
        <Text>hello world</Text>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `uri` instead of `url`

```
<View style={styles.container}>
<Image style={{width:300, height:300}} 
source={{uri: 'https://example.com/image.jpg'}} />
<Text>hello world</Text>
```